# Multiple GMSMarker show/hide consumes time

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have about 4000 markers on the GoogleMap and I am not using clustering. So, at the moment what I do to show/ hide markers on map is below.

```
marker.map = nil 
marker.map = mapView
```

There are some cases where I need to filter out some markers and make them visible else should be hidden. So I can achieve it with about code but with a cost to time.

```
markers.forEach { (marker) in
                if !arrDeviceID.contains(marker.deviceID ?? "") {
                        marker.map = nil
                } else {
                        marker.map = self.googleMapView
                }
            }
```

Same thing in Android there is a property `Visibility` which is working perfect and fast. But in iOS there is no such property.

So what can I do to improve performance.

Comment: instead of having array of Markers and enumerate it with o(n^2), you can have a dictionary of markers which the key is Id and value is marker. you can access each marker with o(n).

Comment: `marker.opacity = 0` to hide the marker not removing it. By  `marker.map = nil` you're removing the overlay from map and adding it back which is taking the time.

Comment: your complexity is of o(n2). you can use a dictionary of markers and iterate arrDeviceId.

Comment: @TheTiger `marker.opacity = 0` will hide the marker but It will still receive the tap I guess. I will go ahead and try that.

Comment: @Mina Looks promising will go ahead and replace array with dictionary.

Comment: @ParthBhuva Can you write an answer with an example for the same?

Comment: @ParthAdroja No it will not. Have you tried? It is similar as setting `alpha` to `0`.

Comment: @TheTiger Yes I tried It gives tap over there and opens InfoWindow.

Comment: For that there is a `property` `isTappable` you can set it to `false`. I just want to say removing and adding is not good idea in your case... it will probably take more time than just hiding and showing.

Comment: @TheTiger Yes that can be done by the cost of time is due to looping so improving the code over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say this is your markers array

```
var markers = [GMSMarker]()
```

prepare dictionary of markers, lets assume your device id is in Int

```
func prepareMarkersDict(markers:[GMSMarker]) -> [Int:GMSMarker]{
    var markerDict = [Int:GMSMarker]()
    for marker in markers{
        markerDict[marker. deviceID] = marker
    }
    return markerDict
}
```

your array of device id which you wants to hide

```
var arrDeviceIDToHide = [Int]()
```

now iterate it and hide the marker

```
let markerDict = prepareMarkersDict(markers:markers)
for deviceId in arrDeviceIDToHide{
   let marker = markerDict[deviceId]
   marker?.map = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the implementation would be something like the following:

```
var markers: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]
func addMarker(with identifier: Int) {
 let marker = GMSMarker(position: someCoordinates)
 markers[identifier] = marker
}
func removeMarker(with identifier: Int) {
  markers[identifier]?.map = nil
}
```